# how to restrict master branch from commits by organisation members also?

Tags: github, version-control, git-branch, branching-and-merging

[image]I am trying to restrict master from any push. I had followed [enter link description here](https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions/) but even after that my team members are able to push the code.I read that the organisation will have access to push .But I want to restrict that as well and keep the push access to only 1 or 2 people. How do I achieve this

Comment: Like here I guess: https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions/ . Restrict pushes to branch for everyone and just name the selected few who can push to `master`.

Comment: yes that will allow the organisation members also to push.Its mentioned in the link @orhtej2

Comment: Can you provide a quote matching your claim?

Comment: updated my post with screenshot @orhtej2

Comment: OK, I re-read the docs and I now understand the confusion. The screenshot says that organisation and repository *ADMINISTARTORS* cannot have their push rights revoked, not all the members of the organisation.

Comment: organisation as in ,members added to the organisation in github who can access the repository I want to change access for that members @orhtej2

Comment: Again, (organisation ADMINISTARTORS) and (repository ADMINISTRATORS), not all members of organisation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187416/discussion-between-yacky-and-orhtej2).